# InstallShield primary output of .csproj has apphost.exe file

Tags: c#, .net-5, installshield

I have several `.NET 5` projects in a solution, and one of them (let's call it `MyMainProject`) has `OutputType` `WinExe`. I added new InstallShield "Basic MSI Project". A few steps later I added to the setup the output of my WinExe project (`MyMainProject.PublishItemsOutputGroup`). The setup builds, but the problem is, instead of having `MyMainProject.exe` I have `apphost.exe`. When in InstallShield project I right-click the [`PublishItemsOutputGroup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60723890/395718) item and select [`Resolve Project Output`](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/IDlgOutputs.htm) I get the list of all items, and in the list `apphost.exe` is properly resolved to `MyMainProject.exe`. But not in the final product.

What should I do to have `apphost.exe` properly named in the installation? I know this file is just a [shim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521078/395718) for `dotnet.exe`, but I like it named the way I like it.

Comment: That's an odd problem to have, given that there should be no apphost.exe file present after the project is built.  A little birdy tells me that InstallShield is pulling files from obj/Release instead of bin/Release.